How do I put an image in the background of the search bar?
That my first post here.
I'm a self-taught developer and I'd really like to learn how to put an image in the background of a search bar.
I can imagine that HTML isn't suitable, but I don't know CSS very well.
As this MND lesson* on CSS suggests, we can embed pre-defined text in what I call the "dialog box" of the search bar box.
I'm pretty sure it's possible to embed a background image in this search bar ( either in .PNG or .SVG format, but I'd prefer to use the vector format if possible ).
But as for the "variable", "attribute" or "property", I don't know which to use or how to formulate it in my code to make it work.
*https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search
I don't have the code acec me at the moment but from memory I had something like this in my CSS :
In HTML :


label {
  display: block;
  font:
    1rem 'Fira Sans',
    sans-serif;
}

input,
label {
  margin: 0.4rem 0;
}
<label for="site-search">Search the site:</label>
<input type="search" id="site-search" name="q" />

<button>Search</button>




Simple with:
input {
  background-image: url("filename.svg");
}

like so:


label {
  display: block;
  font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input,
label {
  margin: 0.4rem 0;
}


/*the code you need*/

input {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Svg_example1.svg");
  background-position: 0;
}
<label for="site-search">Search the site:</label>
<input type="search" id="site-search" name="q" />

<button>Search</button>



Here's another example:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Input field with an icon inside</h2>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>

</body>
</html>




Here is an example of how you would apply a background image to the search bar element:
.search-bar {
  background-image: url('path to your image');
}




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Background Image Input</title>
    <style>
      input [type = 'text'] {
        background-image: url("path to yout image or URL");
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* background-size: 100% 100%;  use this property to display full image in the field  */
       
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text..." />
    
  </body>
</html>



This HTML and CSS code creates an input field with a background image. The CSS sets the background image using the background-image property, and box-sizing: border-box; ensures that padding and border are included in the input field's total width. The placeholder attribute provides a hint text inside the input field.
